# ListView in React Native tutorial cannot reach its scroll to the bottom(Android)

Tags: react-native

[image: Scroll Top(left iOS, right Android)]

[image: Scroll Bottom(left iOS, right Android)]

I made same demo application as React Native tutorial(0.21) instructs, and run app on simulator(iOS 9.2 iPhone 6s, Nexus_5_API_22_x86 avd)

It looks ok, but when I scroll app to its bottom, only iOS app could reach it to the end. Is it just a bug of react ListView component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm right now, but it seems that the ListView hides behind the action-bar of android. What you can do is apply `marginBottom: 20` or `paddingBottom: 20` to `ListView` to scroll completely to the bottom.

Like this-

```
<ListView style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
</ListVIew>
```

Comment: Since react native is not an one-source to cross-platform solution, applying different padding/margin value for each platform would make sense..

Comment: @user2519035 true. But since you're just playing around, I proposed a temporary solution. There could be many ways to fix this. Also, if you add a TabBarIOS to your iOS app, same problem occurs. In that case, applying padding directly to the ListView will make sense.